# Error during mysqldump on performance_schema.query_cache_info

Tags: mariadb

On a production server MariaDB 10.2.13, I actived the plugin query_cache_info.
Suddendly for 5 days, during the daily batch doing dumps (with mysqldump), I have this error :

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `QUERY_CACHE_INFO`': Character set '#4294967295' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file (22)
```

I did

```
reset query cache
```

But the problem come back. I don't find the query which could be the problem.
I don't know how resolve this problem.

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not dump any tables of `performance_schema`, `information_schema` or `mysql`.  The first two are not 'real' tables, and they cannot be reloaded anyway.

95% of Production servers are not helped by, or even hurt by, turning on the Query cache.  Please elaborate on why you are even attempting to use the QC.

Comment: ok to do not dump performance_schema. Didn't know it can not be reloaded. For the use of QC, on some requests I had slow time issue and after tests I saw improved time with QC.

Comment: @user2463696 - A few queries run a lot faster with the QC, but most slow down slightly.  There are many blogs and Q&A giving more details.

Comment: I understand. thx for your feedback.

Comment: @user2463696 - Furthermore, "tests" are rarely reflect "production traffic".  If, for example, there are no `INSERTs` into the table during the 'test', the QC shines gloriously.  But if the table is continually being inserted into, the QC becomes rarely useful.